# primefaces framework doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the next piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>
    <h:form id="sorteoId">
        <p:panel id="pnl" header="Red">
            <h:outputText value="person1" />
        </p:panel>
        <p:draggable for="pnl" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

when I run the project the control draggable or any other primefaces' control doesn't work.

Thx for your help!

Comment: If `p:panel` doesn't show up then check if you have added library or if you use maven check dependency,

Comment: hi, the library has been added but still without work :/

Comment: What is returned by the server as a response and what is the response status? (Right click and then click an option like "View page source" from the sub menu opened. See the HTTP traffic monitor on the "Network" tab for the response status (press F12)).

Comment: hi @Tiny this returned: ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined Sorteo:5:1
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: PrimeFaces JavaScript does not seem to have been loaded for some reason but does the browser show the correct HTML code corresponding the XHTML file?

Comment: the code corresponding the XHTML file is the code I published, I have an only one XHTML file

Comment: You need an empty h:head

Comment: A more specific title would also be nice

Comment: Next time you get an exception/error message, just use it as [search keyword](https://google.com/search?q=Uncaught+Reference+Error%3A+PrimeFaces+is+not+defined) (after removing environment specific details, if any).

Comment: the solution is a empty head: <h:head></h:head>